# How do one solve $ \int_t^T \exp[\int_0^u-( r-\delta_s)ds] dW_u $? Double integral with general deterministic function $\delta(t)$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

How do one solve $ \int_t^T  \exp[\int_0^u-\left( r-\delta_s\right)ds] dW_u $ ?

$\delta(t)$ is a general deterministic function. $r$ is constant.

Comment: Are $r$ and $\delta_u$ deterministic or stochastic?

Comment: @Olaf  
$\delta_u$ and $r$ are deterministic, but only $\delta_u$ is allowed to vary.

Answer (score 1):

There is no analytical solutions to this integral. The conclusions we can draw about this integral are that, if $r$ and $\delta$ are deterministic, it is normal and is independent of the information set $\mathscr{F}_t$. These are probably the most needed properties, for example, in the computation of a zero-coupon bond price under the Hull-White interest rate model, as demonstrated in [question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/21513/extended-hull-white-interest-rate-model-for-zero-coupon-bond/21516#21516). What else are you looking for?

Comment: How do you conclude that there is no analytical solution? I am studying the detailed answer in the link and find it related, but I need more time.

Comment: To say there is no analytical solution is based on my feeling. See also the discussion in this question:https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/21497/how-to-compute-the-stochastic-integral-of-log-normal-process